# How many ways can you pick from a list when for each pick you can either pick 1 or 2 items from the list?

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose you have x amount of bagels, each day you must eat 1 bagel minimum or 2 bagels maximum..how many different ways can you eat all the bagels?

Comment: We assume that all bagels are identical. For comfort we use $n$ rather than $x$.  Let $a_n$ be the number of ways. Argue that for $n\ge 2$,  $a_n=a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}$.

Comment: Note that this is essentially the same as [this problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/789804/how-many-distinct-ways-to-climb-stairs-in-1-or-2-steps-at-a-time).