# given $n$ stairs, how many number of ways can you climb either step up one stair or hop up two?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, recurrence-relations, recursion, recursive-algorithms

this is the question

> given $n$ stairs, how many number of ways can you climb either step up
>   one stair or hop up two?
>   I need to include the number of ways for $n=1$ through $6$ as well.

My question : is step up two stairs and hop up two, is it the same thing? 
however, I tried to do the solution

$n=1$ stair No. of ways $ = 1 = f(2) $

$n= 2$ No. of ways $ = 2 = f(3) = f(2) + f(1) $

$n= 3$ No. of ways $ = 3 = f(4) = f(3) + f(2) $

$n= 4$ No. of ways $ = 5 = f(5) = f(4) + f(3) $

$n= 5$ No. of ways $ = 8 = f(6) = f(5) + f(4) $

$n= 6$ No. of ways $ = 13 =f(7) = f(6) + f(5) $

:

:

for $n$, No. of ways $ = f(n+1) $

because there is a hint saying I could use recursively defined.

Is there other way?

Comment: but there is nothing to be formulated?

Comment: See possibly http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/789804/how-many-distinct-ways-to-climb-stairs-in-1-or-2-steps-at-a-time?rq=1

Comment: thank you :)  but do you know why do we use FIbonacci numbers?

Comment: All solutions in the link uses fibonacci as well, and I would say there isn't really another "elegant" way as the closed formula involves $\sqrt{5}$. But you can always count all cases and add them up, while this will not give you a closed formula.

Comment: There is also a combinatorial solution: http://ms.appliedprobability.org/data/files/Articles%2047/47-1-4.pdf "The Staircase Problem and Fibonacci Numbers" by SIMON ZASLAVSKY and ROGER KHAZAN in Applied Probability Trust 2014

Answer (score 1):

You have correctly observed your recursive pattern. Namely the [Fibonacci Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) defined by:

$$F(n+2)=F(n+1)+F(n),F(0)=1,F(1)=1$$ 
(Note different definitions define different start conditions, this is to fit into your situation)

Now it is possible to derive a formula who gives $F(n)$ only in terms of $n$ but the method is significantly harder than the recursive method above.

It is given by:

$$F(n)=\frac{\left(\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}\right)^n-\left(\frac{1-\sqrt5}{2}\right)^n}{\sqrt5}$$

Note this one starts from 0,1 for the first two terms which is slightly different to your answer which has a zeroth term and starts 1,1.

Given that you only need to do up to $n=6$ this formula is a huge overkill and highly likely beyond what your teacher expected you to do.

Comment: where s√5 comes fron ?

Comment: As I said the math is quite involved. It comes from the equation $x^2-x-1=0$ which is a quadratic equation (not sure if you've studied those yet).