# How Many Ways are There to Climb 10 Stairs Using 1, 2, ..., or an Unlimited Number of Steps?

Tags: logic, recursion

In how many ways can one climb a staircase composed of 10 stairs when each step covers either one stair or two stairs?

This question is very similar to one I have seen with 6 stairs. The solution was to find how many possibilities are there to take one stair at a time, then 2, then 3, and so on. I need help because the number is larger.

Comment: Hint:  There are two ways to climb a flight of $10$ stairs: Climb $8$ stairs (done in some number of ways), and then take a comprising two stairs, or  Climb $9$ stairs (done in some number of ways), and then take a step comprising one stair. Can you see a recursion formula in this description?

Comment: Ok I'll try, using the same method as I said...

Comment: Isn't this exactly the same as one of the linked question? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1554349/

Comment: $f(n) = f(n-2) + f(n-1)$  Now you can start with $f(1) = 1, f(2) = 2$

Comment: Not really the same, but that was the basic concept.

Comment: @2012ssohn indeed.  I saw that and fixed it

Comment: I think I got it...

Comment: Darn it missed something in the question. Please help!

Comment: Could one go down 1 or 2 steps at a time? If so, then this could really change the question but I'm not seeing if this is allowed or not.

Answer (score -1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> The number of $\ds{n}$-steps configurations is given by

\begin{align}
&\sum_{s_{1} = 1}^{2}\ldots\sum_{s_{n} = 1}^{2}
\bracks{s_{1} + \cdots + s_{n} = 10} =
\sum_{s_{1} = 1}^{2}\ldots\sum_{s_{n} = 1}^{2}
\oint_{\verts{z} = 1}{1 \over z^{11 - s_{1} - \cdots - s_{n}}}
\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[5mm] = &\
\oint_{\verts{z} = 1}{1 \over z^{11}}\pars{\sum_{s = 1}^{2}z^{s}}^{n}
\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic} =
\oint_{\verts{z} = 1}{\pars{1 + z}^{n} \over z^{11 - n}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic} =
{n \choose 10 - n}
\end{align}
which is non zero whenever
$\ds{\pars{~n \geq 10 - n \geq 0 \implies 5 \leq n \leq 10~}}$.

> The total number of configurations is given by

$$
\sum_{n = 5}^{10}{n \choose 10 - n} =
\sum_{n = 0}^{5}{n + 5 \choose 5 - n} = \bbx{\ds{89}}
$$