# What's the number of natural solutions of $x_1 + 2x_2 + 3x_3 = n$?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

> $$x_1 + 2x_2 + 3x_3 = n, \qquad x_1, x_2, x_3 \geq 0$$
>
> Find a regression formula (or a recursive function, not sure how it's called in English) to calculate the number of solutions for all $n≥0$.
>
> Find the number of solution for $n=7$.

So far I only got the following generating function

$$f(x) = \left( \sum_{i=0}^\infty x^i \right) \left( \sum_{i=0}^\infty x^{2i} \right) \left( \sum_{i=0}^\infty x^{3i} \right)$$

Comment: Your last formula seems to be incorrect because these sums diverge.

Answer (score 4):

Your generating function
$$f(x)=\sum_{i\geq0}x^i\>\sum_{j\geq0}x^{2j}\>\sum_{k\geq0}x^{3k}={1\over(1-x)(1-x^2)(1-x^3)}$$is correct and leads to the numbers found by @quasi . Write $f$ in the partitioned form
$$f(x)={1\over6}{1\over(1-x)^3}+{1\over4}{1\over(1-x)^2}+{1\over8}{1\over1-x}+{1\over8}{1\over 1+x}+{1\over3}{1\over 1-x^3}\ .$$
Each of the fractions on the RHS has a simple power series expansion.

Comment: Thanks for the affirmation, could you please explain how to get from the generating function to the final result/formula

Comment: It's more or less the partial fraction decomposition.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too sure the generating function helps in this case.

Recursively, it is obvious that the number of ways of solving it $x_1+2x_2=n$ is just $\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor+1$. Thus the number of ways for solving $x_1+2x_2+3x_3=n$ is just
$$\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor \frac{n}{3}\rfloor}\lfloor\frac{i}{2}\rfloor+1$$

(summing over $i$s where $x_3=i$)

which you can split  into cases depending on the parity of $\lfloor\frac{n}{3}\rfloor$ and find a closed form expression for.

Comment: The sum should be
$$
\sum_{\large{{i=0}}}^{\large{\lfloor\frac{n}{3}\rfloor}}
\left(\left\lfloor\frac{n-3i}{2}\right\rfloor+1\right)
$$

Comment: Do you agree with my suggested correction?

Answer (score 1):

For each integer $n$, let $a(n)$ be the number of nonnegative integer triples $(x,y,z)$ such that
$$x+2y+3z=n$$
From the data, the following recursion appears to hold
$$
a(n)=
\begin{cases}
\text{if}\;n<0,\;\text{then}\\[3.5pt]
\qquad 0\\[2.5pt]
\text{else if}\;n=0,\;\text{then}\\[3.5pt]
\qquad 1\\[.6pt]
\text{else}\\[.4pt]
\qquad a(n-1)+a(n-2)-a(n-4)-a(n-5)+a(n-6)\\
\end{cases}
$$
In particular, for $0\le n\le 15$, we get
$$\begin{array}
{
c|c|
c|c|c|c|c|
c|c|c|c|c|
c|c|c|c|c|
} 
\hline
n 
& 0 
& 1 
& 2 
& 3 
& 4 
& 5 
& 6
& 7 
& 8 
& 9 
& 10
& 11 
& 12 
& 13 
& 14 
& 15 
\\ 
\hline
a(n) 
& 1
& 1
& 2
& 3
& 4
& 5
& 7
& 8
& 10
& 12
& 14
& 16
& 19
& 21
& 24
& 27
\\
\hline
\end{array}$$

**Note:**

I initially thought the recursion could be justified via a straightforward application of the principle of inclusion-exclusion, but the argument eludes me now.

**Update:**

Using the OP's generating function approach, together with a key idea from the solution by @Christian Blatter, the claimed recursion can be justified as follows . . .

Clearly, $a(0)=1$, and $a(n)=0$ when $n < 0$.

Working formally, we get
\begin{align*}
&\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\;a(n)x^n
=
1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\;a(n)x^n
\\[6pt]
&
\phantom{\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\;a(n)x^n}
\,=
\left(\prod_{i=0}^\infty x^i\right)
\left(\prod_{i=0}^\infty x^{2i}\right)
\left(\prod_{i=0}^\infty x^{3i}\right)
\\[6pt]
&
\phantom{\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\;a(n)x^n}
\,=
\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)
\left(\frac{1}{1-x^2}\right)
\left(\frac{1}{1-x^3}\right)
\\[6pt]
\implies\;&\left(\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\;a(n)x^n\right)\bigl((1-x)(1-x^2)(1-x^3)\bigr)=1
\\[6pt]
\implies\;&\left(\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\;a(n)x^n\right)(1-x-x^2+x^4+x^5-x^6)=1
\\[6pt]
\implies\;&a(n)-a(n-1)-a(n-2)+a(n-4)+a(n-5)-a(n-6)=0,\;\text{for all}\;n \ge 1
\\[6pt]
\end{align*}
which confirms the claimed recursion.

**New Update:**

Here's another way to justify the claimed recursion . . .

As previously noted, it's clear that for $n < 0$, we have $a(n)=0$.

By direct evaluation, we get the values
$$\begin{array}
{
c|c|c|c|c|c|c|
} 
\hline
n 
& 0 
& 1 
& 2 
& 3 
& 4 
& 5 
\\ 
\hline
a(n) 
& 1
& 1
& 2
& 3
& 4
& 5
\\
\hline
\end{array}$$
and it's then easily verified that the claimed recursion holds for $n\le 5$.

Thus, in what follows, assume $n\ge 6$.

Let $b(n)$ be the number of nonnegative integer ordered pairs $(x,y)$ such that $x+2y=n$.

Then for $a(n)$, we have the recursion
$$a(n)=a(n-3)+b(n)\tag{eq1}$$
and for $b(n)$ we have the recursion
$$b(n)=b(n-2)+1\tag{eq2}$$
Then from $(\text{eq}1)$, we get
$$b(n)=a(n)-a(n-3)\tag{eq3}$$
hence
$$b(n-2)=a(n-2)-a(n-5)\tag{eq4}$$
Using $(\text{eq}3)$ and $(\text{eq}4)$ to make replacements for $b(n)$ and $b(n-2)$ in $(\text{eq}2)$ and then solving for $a(n)$, we get
$$a(n)=a(n-2)+a(n-3)-a(n-5)+1\tag{eq5}$$
hence
$$a(n-1)=a(n-3)+a(n-4)-a(n-6)+1\tag{eq6}$$
Subtracting $(\text{eq}6)$ from $(\text{eq}5)$ and then solving for $a(n)$, we get
$$a(n)=a(n-1)+a(n-2)-a(n-4)-a(n-5)+a(n-6)$$
which completes the proof of the claimed recursion.

Answer (score 1):

A [partition](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Partition.html) of a positive integer $n$ is a multiset of positive integers that sum to $n$. We denote the number of partitions of $n$ by $p(n)$. Also, let $p(n, k)$ be the number of partitions of $n$ into "exactly" $k$ parts. Then

$$p(n) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} p(n, k).$$

Now, consider [Ferrers diagram](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FerrersDiagram.html), where the $n$th row has the same number of dots as the $n$th term in the partition.

[image: Ferrers Diagram]

A conjugate of a partition is the Ferrers diagram, where its rows and columns are flipped. For example,

[image: Img1]

This Ferrers diagram represents the partition $15 = 5 + 4 + 3 + 3$, and the conjugate partition of this is represented as :

[image: Img2]

where $15 = 4 + 4 + 4 + 2 + 1.$ Using this, we can easily recognize that the number of partitions of $n$ with largest part $k$ is the same as the number of partitions into $k$ parts, which is $p(n, k)$. Now we can conclude that the number of partitions of $n$ with all its parts equal or less than $k$, is the same as the number of partitions with equal or less than $k$ parts.

Now, back to the problem :

$$x+2y+3z = n.$$

Notice something? Now look at this :

$$x \cdot 1 + y \cdot 2 + z \cdot 3 = n.$$

We have to make $n$ with $x$ $1$s, $y$ 2s, and $z$ 3s. This equals the number of partitions of $n$, where each part is equal or less than $3$ - since we can only use $1, 2, 3$. Therefore, here's the final answer :

$$p(n, 3) + p(n, 2) + p(n, 1).$$

and one can easily show that $p(n, 1) = 1,\:\:p(n, 2) = \lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor,\:\:p(n, 3) = \rm{round} \left( \frac{n^{2}}{12} \right)$ where the round function gives the nearest integer.

Finally the answer is :

$$\boxed{1 + \lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor + \rm{round} \left( \frac{n^{2}}{12} \right)}$$

and we get $8$ for $n=7$. Read [this](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Emhaiman/math172-spring10/partitions.pdf) for more explanation on the identity I used(and Ferrers diagram).